# Some JavaScript seems to not work: Can't ask questions and new editor not loading

Tags: bug, status-declined, editor, ios, stacks-editor

I'm trying to ask questions (which uses the old editor), but pressing the "review your question" button does nothing. Checking "Answer your own question" does nothing (except make the checkmark appear in the box). Pressing "return" in the title/tags discards the draft.

Also, the new editor doesn't load. The toolbar has grey squares instead of buttons and won't let me type any text. Editing any post with it produces something similar, with no text in the box. This happens on Meta, Teams and Discussions.

[image: boxy toolbar]

Errors:

- [Error] SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name
  (anonymous function) (ask.en.js:64)
- [Error] SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name
  (anonymous function) (stacks-editor.en.js:64)

Browser: Chrome/Safari iOS; Safari MacOS (had to post from desktop Chrome)

The issue is the use of [regex lookbehinds](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) introduced in the code [a week ago](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/pull/262/commits). The most used browser this affects is Safari 3.1 - 16.3 (both desktop and iOS). This includes the second to latest major version of Safari (16.x); the latest (17.x) wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: So many WebKit bugs these days...

Comment: Safari 16 [is not supported](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/) - minimum supported Safari is 17.2. Unfortunately, this most likely means a [tag:status-declined].

Comment: I believe core functionalities of any website should work without any js at all, but what do I know...

Answer (score 2):

As noted on https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/, Safari 16 is not supported. At this time we have no plans to resume supporting Safari 16.

Comment: Well in the past SE used to let users do the basic things (i.e. ask and answer) even with old browsers, and just limit the "nice to have" features for those unsupported browsers, e.g. comments, or even edits. Sad to see this changed so drastically.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Part of the problem here is to do with Apple not supporting a feature that had been supported by other browser vendors for many years. In this case, the feature in question had been supported by Chrome since October 2017 and by Firefox since June 2020. Safari didn't implement the feature until March 2023.

Comment: @Sonic not relevant. Expectation is that anyone will be able to post question, no matter what device or browser version they have. That *was* the case, and that is my point. Not being able to edit, comment, or do anything else is acceptable, IMO. But, not being able to post? I just find it unacceptable.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Out of curiosity, what feature is that?

Comment: @VanitySlug-codidact.com It's linked in the question - regex lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Duh, thanks.