# Can not post question from iPad

Tags: support, bug, ipad, posting

I can’t post a question on SE from my iPad. When I press “Answer your own question” or “Review your question” nothing happens. Is this a bug or is something wrong with my device? It is not the first time this issue happened. I am posting this post from my Android phone.

The software version is 15.3.

---

After the update, the issue have been resolved.

Comment: Did you update your IPAD software device, you should update and try again? You should update and try again.

Comment: @user1176409 thank you for the feedback. I have not updated my iPad. I will update today.

Comment: it would help if you could include which version of iOS and Safari you're using now. Please make an [edit] to your question to add that info.

Comment: I don't have an iPad, nor any other Apple crap but this answer might help to get the version of Safari : https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/443767

Comment: Already reported and declined to fix: [Some JavaScript seems to not work: Can't ask questions and new editor not loading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396804/some-javascript-seems-to-not-work-cant-ask-questions-and-new-editor-not-loadin)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I think updating my iPad would resolve this issue.

Comment: While updating "fix" this, it's absurd that year old browser means one can't use Stack Overflow at all. When Jeff created Stack Overflow, he made it clear anyone can post questions and answers even with old browser, and only the "nice to have" stuff required a modern browser. Pity the new management choose, on purpose, to make the site so much worse and less user friendly.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda - Officially SE only supports a certain number of browser builds, I think the official stance, is essentionally whatever Google, Apple, and Microsoft support on their respective operating systems and devices.  Apple likewise only supports Safari on iPadOS on the newest revisions of the operating system, which as of today is on iPadOS 15.4 (and maybe 15.3/15.2?).  If updating iPadOS solved the problem, then the behavior, was caused by a bug within Safari.